# How to make pictures move or give a continuous motion on websites?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

How can i use my images of same width and height to continuously move on the screen from left to right or right to left.
Like on this page - https://www.reddit.com/r/Nisekoi/

Comment: use marquee tag and place images in it in a div

Comment: You can use marquee tag for this.Well but it is almost gone in html.So suggest you to use jquery-pugins

Comment: You could try <marquee> https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

Comment: use `css key frame` or `jquery` to change the position

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either `Marquee/css key frames/Javascript implementations` for this. But the easiest way is to use `marquee` or  `css`

```
<img class='marquee' src='http://sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo-med.png'>
```

css

```
.marquee { 
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  animation: MarqueeLeft linear 18s infinite;
}

@keyframes MarqueeLeft 
{
  0% { right: -100% }
  100% { right: 100% }
}
```

and with marquee

```
<marquee direction="left">
    <img  src='http://sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo-med.png'>
 </marquee>
```

Check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tintucraju/g9t0e3jf/1/

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
 <img scr="myimage" id="theImage">
```

JavaScript:

```
 var image = document.getElementById("theImage");
 var imageLeft = 0;
 function move(){
     imageLeft++;
     image.style.left = imageLeft + "px";

 }
 setInterval(move, 0);
```

Should Work. You're Welcome.

Comment: But it works. The website is using css keyframes animation

Answer (score 0):

[link](http://www.tagindex.net/html/text/marquee_example.html) for marquee example.

```
<marquee>Default scrolling</marquee>
```

you can give as many images you want in place of "Default scrolling" text